# Merge three ByteArrays together and then split resulting ByteArrays

Tags: java, split, arrays

I have a ByteArray value as `avroBinaryValue` , Schema Name value as String `schemaName` and Last Modified Date value as `lastModifiedDate` in long.

```
byte[] avroBinaryValue = os.toByteArray();
String schemaName = "DEMOGRAPHIC";
long lastModifiedDate = "1379811105109";
```

Now I am planning to convert `schemaName` into `byteArray` as well. Let's name it `byteSchmeName`.

After that, I will convert `lastModifiedDate` to `byteArray` as well. let's name that as well to `byteLMD`.

1. Now what's the best way to concatenate these three `byteArrays` together.

   avroBinaryValue + byteSchemaName + byteLMD
2. Secondly, after concatenating these three byteArrays together, I want to split the resulting `byteArrays` in such a way such that I will be able to get all the three respective byteArrays properly...

Is it possible to do that? Any help will be appreciated.

**NOTE:-**

All the three byteArrays value will be different in different scenarios.. I am looking the most efficient way to store the resulting byteArrays in such a way such that it doesn't take that much space on the disk. I dont want to serialize it again since avroBinaryValue that I am getting is coming from Avro Data Serialization.. So I want to convert the other two things as well in ByteArray so that I can merge all three together into a single ByteArray.

Comment: if you are trying to write the data to disk and read it again, you can use DataOutputStream and DataInputStream (along with FileOutputStream and FileInputStream, of course).

Comment: I will be writing to Cassandra database so that's why I said to disk..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a format. You have the following

```
byte[] avroBinaryValue = os.toByteArray();
String schemaName = "DEMOGRAPHIC";
long lastModifiedDate = 1379811105109L;
```

I guess `avroBinaryValue` can be variable length and so can `schemaName`. For all intents and purposes, `lastModifiedDate` fits in a long, ie. 8 bytes.

If you want to serialize this (other than using `Serializable`), you'll have to use a specific format that will tell you what you are reading and when to stop readin it. For example

```
Offset  Length (in bytes)      Purpose
   0           4               - length of avroBinaryValue array
   4           X               - avroBinaryValue array
  4+X          4               - length of of schemaName byte array
 4+X+4         Y               - schemaName byte array
4+X+4+Y        8               - value of lastModifiedDate
```

Also decide if you want big-endian or small-endian byte order.

So you write your three fields as described in the format and you read it the same way.

---

Here's an example done in memory where `os` is a `String` (for simplicity)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String os = "whatever os is";
    byte[] avroBinaryValue = os.getBytes();
    String schemaName = "DEMOGRAPHIC";
    long lastModifiedDate = 1379811105109L;

    byte[] schemaNameBytes = schemaName.getBytes();

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(byteOs);
    out.writeInt(avroBinaryValue.length);
    out.write(avroBinaryValue);
    out.writeInt(schemaNameBytes.length);
    out.write(schemaNameBytes);
    out.writeLong(lastModifiedDate);

    // write done

    byte[] allWrittenBytes = byteOs.toByteArray();

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(allWrittenBytes));

    int sizeAvro = in.readInt();
    avroBinaryValue = new byte[sizeAvro];
    in.read(avroBinaryValue, 0, sizeAvro);

    int sizeSchema = in.readInt();
    schemaNameBytes = new byte[sizeSchema];
    in.read(schemaNameBytes, 0, sizeSchema);

    lastModifiedDate = in.readLong();

    // read done

    System.out.println(new String(avroBinaryValue));
    System.out.println(new String(schemaNameBytes));
    System.out.println(lastModifiedDate);
}
```

It prints

```
whatever os is
DEMOGRAPHIC
1379811105109
```

---

I understand you are trying to save space, but it might just be better to write each field to its own column or use a standard format like XML or JSON to serialize your fields.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Yes you are correct, avroBinaryValue will be of variable length and schemaName as well can be of variable length..But most of the times, it will be fixed as well, lets suppose all the schemaName will be of length 8.  But LMD will always be a long and it should be of 8 bytes... If possible, can you provide an example basis on my above scenario to see how it can be done in Java. It will help me in my understanding process..

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T I've posted an in-memory example.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Yes I understand totally, it will be better to use JSON or write it as a seperate column.. But I cannot write as a seperate column bcoz I am going to use Cassandra and each column name will get repeated whenever we are storing the data so it will be a waste of space there... In general, I know its a silly question but if I am using JSON and serializing it to JSON then which approach is better? The approach that we are doing right now or with JSON? which will be better in terms of performance?

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T In terms of size, you will write a little less bytes with the above approach. However, you have to write all this logic for parsing/generating the bytes. With JSON, you can use any of the many available libraries, Gson, jackson, Simple-json, etc.

Comment: I know its a pretty old post but trying to understand whether in this example we are using Big Endian or Small Endian byte order? And how do we know which we are following?

Comment: @trekkie You'll have to be consistent. If you write big endian, you have to read big endian. I don't know what writeLong() does by default, but it should be explained in the javadoc.

Comment: This is what it is written in the java docs - `Writes a long to the underlying output stream as eight bytes, high byte first. In no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by 8.` which means it is using Big Endian? Right? If yes, that means High Bytes is also called Big Endian?

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T I do believe so. Try it. You can specify which way to read the `long`/`int` with `ByteBuffer`. There's a method that accepts the endian-ess.